# How to show two div alternatively (show one and hide another div on same place) on check box click using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function myFunction() {
   if (document.getElementById("ChkChildIssue").checked)
   {
    document.getElementById("dhamale").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("sachin").style.display="block"; 
   }
   else
   {
     document.getElementById("dhamale").style.display="block";
     document.getElementById("sachin").style.display="none"; 
   }
 }
</script>

<body>
<input type="Checkbox" name="ChkChildIssuess" id="ChkChildIssue"  onclick="myFunction();" />Include Child issue</br>

<div id="dhamale" > </div>
<div id="sachin" style="display:none;" > </div> // i want this div by default diaplay
```

When checkbox is checked, then div "dhamale" will be hidden and div "sachin" will be displayed and vice-versa .

But when checkbox get checked that time, div "sachin" is not being displayed.

```
(document.getElementById("sachin").style.display="block" //this is not working
```

Comment: It works for me in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/uKU5p/. Might be a browser issue.

Comment: On firefox 23.0.1 and IE 8 works too. Is javascript enabled on your browser? What is exactly the behaviour in your borwser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work. But why use javascript?
you can perfectly solve this using css.

```
<div class="toggle-wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" name="toggler"/>Toggler
    <div class="content">
        <div class="active">This is the active box</div>
        <div class="inactive">This is the inactive box</div>
    </div>
</div>

.content {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}

.content > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .content .active {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TfceP/